# Google sheets Xlookup dont work but need results in table the max date on the condition of userlist

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, google-sheets-arrays

Need some help with some data processing. 
[Link of the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/113-oL3DYtROJAsR1P1RWEF5PHJc5_KLXbUNwkZOLkl0/edit?usp=sharing)

---

Example - I need on  :

`Page-2-Seznam članov > Coloumn C` : It needs to be the max dates.
The function need to search on the liste the name from `Page-2-Seznam članov > Coloumn B` and in area `Page-3-Podaljsave` to give the outpoot from the same person the **exact max date** from `Page-3-Podaljsave > Coloumn E`

`Page-2-Seznam članov > Coloumn D` : It needs to be the max dates.
The function need to search on the liste the name from `Page-2-Seznam članov > Coloumn B` and in area `Page-3-Podaljsave` to give the outpoot from the same person the **exact max date** from `Page-3-Podaljsave > Column F`

I tried functions like `filter` like `match` etc, but i cant get any result.
 Can Someone help?

Dont know about `Query`, but I know if I input a `=Query` then the whole opening of the document takes a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1 :

> `Page-2-Seznam članov > Coloumn C` : It needs to be the max dates.
>   The function need to search on the list the name from `Page-2-Seznam članov > Coloumn B` and in area `Page-3-Podaljsave` to give the outpoot from the same person the exact max date from `Page-3-Podaljsave > Coloumn E`

In `Page 2 > column C > cell C3` you can use `vlookup`.

```
=VLOOKUP(B3,'Page-3-Podaljsave'!$B:$E,4,false)
```

A `=sort` function to guarantee that the output will be the **max** date available.

```
=VLOOKUP(B3,sort('Page-3-Podaljsave'!$B:$E,4,false),4,false)
```

Then use an `arrayformula` to cover the range.

```
=arrayformula(VLOOKUP(B:B10,sort('Page-3-Podaljsave'!$B:$E,4,false),4,false))
```

Be careful, the bigger the range in this lookup, the slower the sheet will be to open/process new data.

---

Problem 2 :

> `Page-2-Seznam članov > Coloumn D` : It needs to be the max dates.
>   The function need to search on the liste the name from `Page-2-Seznam članov > Coloumn B` and in area `Page-3-Podaljsave` to give the outpoot from the same person the **exact max date** from `Page-3-Podaljsave > Column F`

Same idea :

```
=arrayformula(VLOOKUP(B3:B10,sort('Page-3-Podaljsave'!$B:$F,5,false),5,false))
```

---

You can combine the two formulas in a single array with this in `C3` :

```
={arrayformula(iferror(VLOOKUP(B3:B10,sort('Page-3-Podaljsave'!$B:$E,4,false),4,false))),arrayformula(iferror(VLOOKUP(B3:B10,sort('Page-3-Podaljsave'!$B:$F,5,false),5,false)))}
```

---

Bonus : you can reduce `'Page-3-Podaljsave'!$B:$E` to an array with only two columns : `{'Page-3-Podaljsave'!$B:$B,'Page-3-Podaljsave'!$E:$E}` then use it in the function like this :

```
={
arrayformula(iferror(
  VLOOKUP(B3:B10,
    sort({'Page-3-Podaljsave'!$B:$B,'Page-3-Podaljsave'!$E:$E},2,false),
  2,false))),
arrayformula(iferror(
  VLOOKUP(B3:B10,
    sort({'Page-3-Podaljsave'!$B:$B,'Page-3-Podaljsave'!$E:$E},2,false),
  2,false)))
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks alot - i have totaly forgot the sort possibilitie. Thanks allot. Will try now everythink :D

Comment: @BorutMyStur Please checkout [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchangec.com/help/someone-answers)